# Try Except Not Catching TimeoutException (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, try-except

I'm using Selenium to help navigate around a Salesforce org to add some states. My code works except on the rare occasion I'll run into an internal server error (which happens once every thousand or so states).

I've tried to fix this with a try/except loop but it still failed with a TimeoutException, the exact thing I called out in the except clause.

I've also imported any Selenium related modules I need, including the TimeoutException.

Any reason why it'd throw an error even though it's in the exception?

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


#There's some code above this but I'll encounter the server error after clicking this save button
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurenew:j_id1:blockNew:j_id43:addButton').click()

#The try/except loop to handle that if it comes up.
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.msgIcon'))) #This is the line that gives the error
except TimeoutException:
    print('Internal Server Error')
    driver.refresh()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurecountry:form:stateRelatedListComponent:configStateCountryRelList:list:j_id50:buttonAddNew').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurenew:j_id1:blockNew:j_id9:nameSectionItem:editName').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurenew:j_id1:blockNew:j_id9:nameSectionItem:editName').send_keys(countriesAndStates[countryCode][stateCode])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurenew:j_id1:blockNew:j_id9:codeSectionItem:editIsoCode').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurenew:j_id1:blockNew:j_id9:codeSectionItem:editIsoCode').send_keys(stateCode)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'configurenew:j_id1:blockNew:j_id9:activeSectionItem:editActive').click()
```

Error I get on the WebDriverWait line below try:

> Exception has occurred: TimeoutException line 249, in 
> WebDriverWait(driver,
> 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
> '.msgIcon'))) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:

Comment: It must be that the TimeoutException is coming from somewhere else, and not from `WebDriverWait()`.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback.

Comment: I edited my post and added the error message. It comes out specifically for that WebDriverWait() line.

Comment: The error traceback says the error happened on line 249, which clearly does not match the code you posted.  So it must be that the real line 249 in your code does not have the same try/except block.

Comment: Can you show us that section of your actual code?

Comment: This is that section: Line 249 is the WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.msgIcon')))

Comment: If the preceding 248 lines are irrelevant, then surely you can reproduce an error using code that does not include it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Showing us line 249 by itself is not enough.  We need to see if there is, or is not, a try/except block _surrounding_ that line.

Comment: with the information currently available in the question, it's impossible to solve the problem